# Authenticate a user only with password

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm making a Flutter application where the user has to register and log in with email and password.

Is there a way to ask the registered user to enter his password every time he wants to log in ?

The output would be like this :

*Welcome back UserName@email.com*

*please type your password to enter the app*

I've searched the subject in the FirebaseAuth documentation, but couldn't find any relative information.

Comment: so, you want firebase to not save the user for the next app opening ?

Comment: I want firebase to register the user (with email and password), then ask for the user's password in every app opening

Comment: You are working on Banking app? On a web, you can choose to use session storage.

Comment: Why you want to save user email but not a password? Mean just kept user logged in.

Comment: The app contains sensitive user's informations, that's why I need the user to type his password every time he launches the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly sign any current user out when loading the page. See the bottom of the documentation page on [email+password authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) for an example.

Comment: What happens when the user opens same app in a new tab?

Comment: If the tabs run as part of the same process/share local storage, it'll sign the user out in both tabs. You could try to call sign-out just before the **last** tab gets closed, but it may be tricky to get that working reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically and practically speaking, you would use some type of local storage to signal to your app that the user is signed in, or out. If you use page load events only to signout the user, they will be signed out when opening a new tab which would probably be annoying.

You could use an unload event to prompt the user "You will be signed out of this application when you leave this page"

Doing all of that, the onload event could look for that auth state variable in local storage.

Comment: Firebase authentication not use cookies.

Comment: Shucks, I thin you might be right. Let me reword my answer.

Comment: this is related only to web ?